# Laravel 5.1: Views, clarifications

Tags: php, yii, laravel-5

So when I initially put my hands on Laravel, I was transistioning off Yii1. In Yii, we'd use plain PHP templates; which I don't mind, since I actually like them that way.

However, when I learned about Blade and how Laravel documented Blade back and forth and barely even mentioned the use of bare PHP templates, I was...irked.

I threw together a project that would provide me with just a PHP view engine. But just a few minutes ago, I actually saw it: `PhpEngine.php`. Diggin deeper, I facepalmed; I can not just go and deprecated my project, but I can also go and dig deeper.

It is sooo confusing, so I am looking ot have a teeny tiny bit of questions answered:

- When I use `View::addNamespace()`, I can just do `view("foo::my.template")` too, right?
- How do I actually use a layout/template? As in, I have the document written, into which I want to rende rmy views. How do I do that with *bare* PHP views? IN blade, we get `@extend` or something, but I can not seem to find that for raw PHP templates.
- Where can I see some proper view docs and examples instead of the laravel.com ones, which push Blade that much?

Answer (score 0):

> When I use `view::addNamespace()`, I can just do `view("foo::my.template")` too, right?

Yes. It does. Generally this format is applied third party packages. For example, if you have in mind using a package, you call the view namespace as:

```
$this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/path/to/views', 'foo');
```

Now you are able to call view as `view('foo::whatever')`

> How do I actually use a layout/template? As in, I have the document written, into which I want to rende rmy views. How do I do that with bare PHP views? IN blade, we get @extend or something, but I can not seem to find that for raw PHP templates.

I do not understand what `I can not seem to find that for raw PHP templates` means. But let me show you an example using blade system:

1. Create a layout file:

   ```
   // master.blade.php
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <title>@yield('title')</title>
   <head>
   <body>
       @yield('body')
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

   As you can notice above, there are two "sections" that their content can be changed according to each view that extends this layout: **title** and **body**.
2. Extending the layout for each view

   ```
   //contact.blade.php
   @extends('master')
   @section('title')
       Contact us
   @stop
   @section('body')
       <h1>Thank you for contact us</h1>
   @stop
   ```

   Notice how `title` and `body` are set using @section tag. Inside of each one you define the content to be displayed. Finally, in your controller just call `view('foo::contact')` or `view('contact')` according to your needs.

> Where can I see some proper view docs and examples instead of the laravel.com ones, which push Blade that much?

Well, blade system is not too much deep. I consider that laravel's docs is enough complementing your knowledge with this side.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! What i meant with my second question is, that in Yii1, I had a "main layout" and my view files. So when I called `$this->render("myview");`, the view would get rendered, and then the layout would be loaded and the view placed into there as `<?=$content?>`. Is that possible with Laravel, at all?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I did in the code above. Just use your views and layout with `.blade.php` extension. In the example `@yield('body')` is the same as `<?=$content?>` for your case.